# How to set SameSite:Strict for all cookies in spring 5

Tags: spring, cookies

Is there anyone can tell me how to add SameSite:Strict to all cookies created in spring 5.1? I know in spring 4, this attribute was not supported. But since Spring 5.1, It can be as declare at [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d74e09a92505060a8826d5ad713db4dec4384a74/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/server/session/CookieWebSessionIdResolver.java#L105-L116)!

But I don't know how to apply this to my project? Where should I put it? Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add SameSite attribute to my project using Spring because Object javax.servlet.http.Cookie hasn't supported this attribute. But I could custom cookie header in Apache tomcat (version 9.0.11) by add the following line to conf/context.xml:

```
<Context allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">
    ...
    <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.custom.coyote.TomcatCoyoteCustomer"/>
</Context>
```

And then create a project "CustomCookieProcessor" with TomcatCoyoteCustomer class that extends Rfc6265CookieProcessor class, override method generateHeader and append "SameSite:Strict" to cookie header. Finally, I copy jar file of "CustomCookieProcessor" project to folder lib of Tomcat. You can read more detail about CookieProcessor of Apache Tomcat at  [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/cookie-processor.html)!